# Clarification on session_start() when using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, session

I recently got the following error in my logs:

`session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`

I am new to using sessions so I am not surprised. I use the following code in my header.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
      if(!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
         header("Location: login.php");
      }
?>
```

I mostly use AJAX to interact with some files that handle database-related functions. Do I need to add the session_start() on my backend php files too? I am currently doing this:

```
<?php
    $inputvalues = $_POST;
    $errors = false;
    $result = false;
    include_once 'database.php';

    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

    $uid = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
     
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

    if( !$errors ) {
            // insert your query
            $mysqli->query("
                INSERT INTO `contributions`(`uid`, `contributionname`, `contributiontype`, `contributionamount`, `employee`) 
                values ('".$uid."', '".$inputvalues['contributionname']."', '".$inputvalues['contributiontype']."', '".$inputvalues['contributionamount']."', '".$inputvalues['employee']."');
            ");
                        // select your query
        $addresult = "Success";
        $returnResult = $addresult;
        }

        // close connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        // print result for ajax request
        echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

        exit;
    ?>
```

Is this what is causing my error?

Comment: Are you talking about admin panel backed

Comment: Somewhere there is an ```echo``` some string or Space in your file ```database.php``` . Can u show your ```database.php``` code?

Comment: There should be no output printed(test/html/space) before you use session_start();. please check for this.

Comment: One more thing you can do keep that ```session_start();``` in the top of the page & check what error you are getting. I think you'll get the same error but from a different file.

Comment: @PavanBaddi No, I mean in my PHP files which aren't visible but just get info through AJAX to add/edit/delete data in the database.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll check for empty spaces. I'll move the `session_start()` right to the beginning.